# project one collection into another and keep them in sync

Tags: c#, collections

I often have to project one collection into another. That would be very easy using Select operator from linq to objects:

```
var targetCollection = sourceCollection.Select(source => new Target
{ 
   Source = source,
   //some other stuff here
}
```

But I have to keep the collections eventually synchronized. When new items are added or removed from the sourceCollection, the changes has to be reflected in targetCollection. I have to do something like this:

```
void OnSourceCollectionChanged(){
   SyncCollections(sourceCollection, targetCollection)
}

void SyncCollections(ICollection<Source> sourceCollection, ICollection<Target> targetCollection)
{
   //find items that are no longer present
   var newItems = sourceCollection.Where(s => !targetCollection.Any(t => t.Source == s));
   //find items that were added
   var oldItems = targetCollection.Where(t => !sourceCollection.Any(s => t.Source == s));

   foreach(var oldItem in oldItems)  targetCollection.Remove(oldItem);

   foreach(var source in newItems){
       var target = new Target{ Source = source };
       targetCollection.Add(target);
   }
}
```

I believe there are already good libraries to deal with such scenarios. Can you recommend me some?

I think of API where I just specify the projection and maybe 'equality comparer' to compare source and target item:

```
var synchronizer = new CollectionSynchronizer<Source, Target>(
    source => new Target
    {
        Source = source
    });

synchronizer.Sync(sourceCollection, targetCollection);

//or specify filter as well:
synchronizer.Sync(
    sourceCollection.Where(s => s.Created > DatTime.Now.AddMinutes(-5)),
    targetCollection);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [`ObservableCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653375(v=vs.110).aspx) for that:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var observableList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        var syncList = new List<string>(observableList);

        observableList.CollectionChanged += (o,e) => { 
            foreach (var item in e.NewItems){
                syncList.Add((string)item);
            }
        };

        observableList.Add("Test");
        Console.WriteLine(syncList[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's way far from what I need, @venerik ;)

Answer (score 0):

In case your source collection implements INotifyCollectionChanged and is IEnumerable (e.g. ObservableCollection) you can do a wrapper collection.

```
public class ProxyCollection<TProxy, TSource> : IEnumerable<TProxy>, IDisposable{
    private readonly Dictionary<TSource, TProxy> _map = new Dictionary<TSource, TProxy>();
    private readonly Func<TSource, TProxy> _proxyFactory;
    private readonly ObservableCollection<TSource> _sourceCollection;

    public ProxyCollection(ObservableCollection<TSource> sourceCollection, Func<TSource, TProxy> proxyFactory){
        _sourceCollection = sourceCollection;
        _proxyFactory = proxyFactory;
        AddItems(sourceCollection);

        _sourceCollection.CollectionChanged += OnSourceCollectionChanged;
    }

    public IEnumerator<TProxy> GetEnumerator(){
        return _map.Values.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator(){
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    private void AddItems(IEnumerable<TSource> sourceCollection){
        foreach (TSource sourceItem in sourceCollection){
            AddProxy(sourceItem);
        }
    }

    private void AddProxy(TSource source){
        _map[source] = _proxyFactory(source);
    }

    private void OnSourceCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e){
        switch (e.Action){
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                AddItems(e.NewItems.Cast<TSource>());
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                RemoveItems(e.OldItems.Cast<TSource>());
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
                ReplaceItems(e.OldItems.Cast<TSource>(), e.NewItems.Cast<TSource>());
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move:
                throw new NotImplementedException("Your code here");
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
                throw new NotImplementedException("Your code here");
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
    }

    private void ReplaceItems(IEnumerable<TSource> oldItems, IEnumerable<TSource> newItems){
        RemoveItems(oldItems);
        AddItems(newItems);
    }

    private void RemoveItems(IEnumerable<TSource> sourceItems){
        foreach (TSource sourceItem in sourceItems){
            _map.Remove(sourceItem);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose(){
        _sourceCollection.CollectionChanged -= OnSourceCollectionChanged;

        //optionally
        foreach (IDisposable proxy in _map.Values.OfType<IDisposable>()){
            proxy.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

It can also implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`. In this case you have to raise `CollectionChanged` event with appropriate parameters in `OnSourceCollectionChanged` method.

Also you can create an internal List collection and expose it. In this case proxy collection will have proxies at same indices as source collection. It's up to your needs.

Comment: I got your point. Thanks. Just few notes: 1. making the ProxyCollection IDisposable is too hardcore, because all classes that have disposable members should be also disposable. 99% ProxyCollection would be member of viewmodel or similar. In that case also the viewmodels would have to be disposable. 2. if source collection is observablecollection I would also derive ProxyCollection from ObservableCollection. 3. it is nice for simple scenarios, but in order to reuse it should be more flexible. e.g how would you handle multithreading?

Comment: @Liero why hardcore? Why not to dispose a viewmodel?. Yes, you can derive from `ObservableCollection`. I gave you just an idea. Anyway it's better than to be tight to Created field and to check it every n minutes or so. About multi threading - it goes beyond your question. In my current project, all domain repositories work in one thread. All synchronization is done in outer code.